# run geth light mode looking for peers forever

Tags: go-ethereum

i run a geth light mode node on Ubuntu by
geth  --syncmode "light" --identity "mydev" --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "/root/mygeth/chain" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1 console

But it always looking for peers and peer count is 0

Do I need to add some peers and where to find

Thanks

Comment: How long you been waiting for peers? Usually it takes few hours. At least this is what happened with my light node.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or NAT network? Try port forwarding the p2p port to the machine running geth.

Comment: thanks. if i submit a raw transaction to geth light node, it will be the same as submitting to geth full node?

Answer (score 1):

When full nodes decide to serve light nodes, they use much more bandwidth and read a lot off of their disk, so most people don't serve light nodes. I've had problems running any kind of nodes on Ubuntu, so that might be your problem. Also, there are tons of light nodes waiting for new ones. Don't try to run a light node during ICO, you will never find one.

Comment: if I add some node as peers by admin I found the node by etherscan nodes. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you saying you found etherscan's nodes? If you add any light node serving node, and add it via admin.addPeer, it will start serving you. etherscan nodes are just like any nodes